# Android how programatically change <ProgressBar ..... android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" to different position?

Tags: java, android

On Android, how programmatically I can change the ProgressBar, to show itself on different heights, as seen and work using the XML :

```
<ProgressBar ..... android:layout_marginBottom="100dp" ?
```

When I change on android:layout_marginBottom=”xxxdp” it change it location, in deferent height. But it fixed. I need to move it up and down during runtime, 
I need to show this ProgressBar in different  location from listView Bottom during application running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `layout_*` attributes refer to the parent layout's `LayoutParams` in code.

If the parent layout params is of type [`ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams.html) e.g. the parent is a `LinearLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`, you can modify it and call `requestLayout()` to have the changes take effect:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)progressBar.getLayoutParams();
params.bottomMargin += 123;
progressBar.requestLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

If ProgressBar's parent is `RelativeLayout`, use `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = progbar.getLayoutParams();
int margin = lp.marginBottom;
margin += your_value;
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, margin);
progbar.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.
The code:
progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarLevelLine);
seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.AlarmTrigerLeveBar1);  
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
  public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser)
  {
  
How I can use the "progress" int to show the progressBar (progressBarLevelLine) on deferent height... as it was on the XML android:layout_marginBottom="xxxdp"
Can you shaer sample code ?